# referencia a campo calculado en clausula where?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

como puedo hacer referencia al campo calculado "total" en una misma query en la clausula where?

```
    SELECT pedidos.id
     , clientes.nombre
     , SUM( articulos.precio ) AS total
  FROM pedidos
INNER JOIN clientes
        ON clientes.id = pedidos.id_clientes
LEFT JOIN articulos
       ON articulos.id_pedidos = pedidos.id
WHERE total>10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las bases de datos no entienden los alias de los campos.

Los alias se ponen una vez terminado el query, porque se usan solo para hacer el display de las consulta (o sea, ponerle el nombre a la columna en la salida de la consulta).

Por lo tanto, no podes hacer referencia al alias, porque no sabe que es.

Si vos queres hacer referencia a un campo calculado, tenes que volver a calcularlo cada vez que lo necesites.

```
SELECT pedidos.id
     , clientes.nombre
     , SUM( articulos.precio ) AS total
  FROM pedidos
INNER JOIN clientes
        ON clientes.id = pedidos.id_clientes
LEFT JOIN articulos
       ON articulos.id_pedidos = pedidos.id
WHERE SUM( articulos.precio )>10
```

Igual, no se la estrctura de tus tablas, pero esta consulta anda sin un `group by`?

OP no aclaro el tema del group by, que si es sql server y usamos un sum tiene que ir si o si (como lo aclaro Patricio en un comentario).

La consulta en realidad deberia ser asi:

```
SELECT pedidos.id
     , clientes.nombre
     , SUM( articulos.precio ) AS total
FROM pedidos
INNER JOIN clientes
        ON clientes.id = pedidos.id_clientes
LEFT JOIN articulos
       ON articulos.id_pedidos = pedidos.id
GROUP BY pedidos.id, clientes.nombre
HAVING SUM(articulos.precio) > 10
```

Comment: siempre debe llevar groupby?

Comment: si vas a usar funciones de agregacion y siempre y cuando no impacten a todos los datos de la tabla y no haya otros campos no calculados, si. Si no, como sabe que sumar? @Ivxn